# Android App compatibility issues for Samsung S4

Tags: android

I have completed my android app using Multiple apk technique.So I have used manifest filter,i.e., compatible-screen tag . Now suddenly I found that the app is not compatible with Samsung S4, i.e. it is not showing in market. 
I found out in a post that the correct bucket for the Samsung Galaxy S4 is as follows:

```
<screen
   android:screenDensity="480"
   android:screenSize="normal" />
```

Will this work or not. Because I have created an apk file, which should only support S4 or Xperia Z mobiles(1080x1920) not Tablets. Please help me asap.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you share link to post with fix?